# Added a new field mapping and want to reindex only that field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added a new field property to an existing field and now I want to reindex only the newly added field property.

My old index mappings were

```
{
 "org_assignee_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "shingle_original" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "shingle_original",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
            "standard" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
            "standard_shingle" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard_shingle",
              "fielddata" : true
            }
          },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
}
```

I added a new analyzer and added an extra property to the field:

```
PUT
{
  "properties": {
    "td_assignee_country_code": {
    "type":"text",
      "fields": {
        "standard_stopwords": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer":"standard_stopwords",
          "fielddata":true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And my new field is:

```
{
 "org_assignee_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "shingle_original" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "shingle_original",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
            "standard" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
            "standard_shingle" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard_shingle",
              "fielddata" : true
            }
          },
          "standard_stopwords" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "analyzer" : "standard_stopwords",
              "fielddata" : true
            },
          "fielddata" : true
        },
}
```

with only the last field property added.

I don't want to reindex the whole thing again as my data set is very large and the initial index took about 6 hours.

I have the raw data uploaded already and I was wondering how it is possible to reindex only the newly added field property? That is, only index the 'org_assignee_name.standard_stopwords' from the raw data set and keep the other field properties the same index or ignore it during the reindex process?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) as mentioned in the link:

> The update API also supports passing a partial document, which is
> merged into the existing document

More specifically follow the example of [update part of docoument](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_update_part_of_a_document) which is exactly what you want

Comment: I heard that for new fields (name, age), reindexing only the new field is possible but for adding a field type (name.first, age.current), it is not possible. Does the update API allow adding a new field type and will I have to use scripting to reindex the new field type?

Answer (score 0):

U may look into [Dynamic Mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/dynamic-mapping.html). It resolved my problem as same as you have. U can also update your setting to dynamic so in future if new field is added than it can easily be handled.

Comment: This can add a lot of fields and can cause unexpected issue in production, like numberformat exception and can be difficult to debug, its good for small and non critical applications

Comment: No issues, its my pleasure to helo and guide community

Comment: Is Dynamic mapping something that is set to 'true' by default or will I have to set it before indexing?

Comment: @JohnLee, By default it is enable.....Once it find new fild than it Will add with its default setting. But sometime it is good practice to initialize it before indexing in order to make customizable as we want.